# Using GE Plugin, how do I programmatically put placemarks in folders?

Tags: c#, treeview, google-earth-plugin

Sorry for the incessant questions but I just can't seem to get the hang of this API.

This would seem to be a very simple operation but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I create a folder in the PluginReady() callback:

```
    folder = ge1.createFolder("Sites");
    folder.setName("Sites");
    kmlTreeView1.ParseKmlObject(folder);
```

With the folder created I wait for data to come in that will create a placemark that goes in this folder.  When that data arrives I create a placemark and then attempt to put it into the kmltreeview 'Sites' folder:

```
    //kmlTreeView1.ParseKmlObject(placemark);
    KmlTreeViewNode node = kmlTreeView1.GetNodeById("Sites");
    node.ApiObject.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
    ge1.getFeatures().appendChild(node.ApiObject);
```

I believe the placemark is in the folder because when I double click the folder a balloon pops up pointing to the placemark.  However, the folder does not have a plus sign to indicate there is something in it.  The kmltreeview1 property "ShowPlusMinus" is set to true.

If someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KmlTreeView doesn't create any kml at all ever...if you load a empty KmlFolder into the tree then it is an empty kmlFolder. If you then do something with the KmlFolder it is not going to change what is in the tree.

For example, if you add features to that same KmlFolder after you have create a treenode from it they will not be shown in the treeview - because you haven't added them to the treeview, you have added them to the KmlFolder.

In your example, you would have to remove the empty sites node from the tree.
Then create a new node based on the folder that has some contents and then add that back to the tree.

```
KmlTreeViewNode node = kmlTreeView1.GetNodeById("Sites"); // get the empty node you added to the tree
node.ApiObject.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark); // get the KmlFolder and add a placemark
ge1.getFeatures().appendChild(node.ApiObject); // add the KmlFolder and features to the plugin
kmlTreeView1.Nodes.RemoveByKey("sites"); // remove the empty node from the tree...
kmlTreeView1.ParseKmlObject(node.ApiObject); // add the KmlFolder that contains your placemark
```

On a side note - the KmlTreeView is essentially designed to load KML files into it, and to sync with the plugin. Whilst you can create individual tree nodes like this it isn't how it was designed to be used...

Comment: Once again Fraser, your repository of knowledge about this seems endless.  That worked perfectly and I am getting much closer to having a nice working GUI for our customer.  This should be about all I need on the KMLTreeView side of things.  The only other thing I'm wanting to do is load in some kmz files and I'm almost done with that.

I do realize I'm doing things in an unorthodox way.  Perhaps once I get the rest of it further along I can play around with creating and loading kml files instead of doing it this way.

Thanks again.

Comment: No worries...I know a lot about the KmlTreeView and the control libray you are using because I wrote it, so I do have an unfair advantage in that regard. It is worth noting the controls are far from perfect and so answering your questions does help to see how things could be improved...

Comment: Super.  I'm glad I'm of some use then. ;)

Comment: Hi Fraser, there may be some sort of problem using FetchKMLLocal and loading the kml into a folder using the above method.  Using FetchKml works fine.  With Local, the kml loads but when I click on the folder's plus sign the plus sign goes away.  The folder stays.  I can add it to GEPlugin issues or I can ask a question here and include screen shots.  Or, perhaps, I am just doing something wrong again...

Comment: Please use the wiki comments on the project page for questions about the control library. http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/KmlTreeView